# Odd and even number using switch case

Tags: c

I want to print the value as well as its type

Input:

```
1
3
5
78
10
```

Output:

```
Odd 1
Odd 3
Odd 5
Even 78
Odd 11
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[4],b,c;


    for(b=0 ; b<=4 ; b++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[b]);
    }
    for (c=0 ; c<=4 ; c++)
    {
            switch (a[c]%2)
            {
                case 0 :
                    printf ("Even %d\n",a[c]);
                    break;
                case 1 :
                    printf ("Odd %d\n",a[c]);
                    break;

            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the last output `Odd 11` instead of `Even 10`?

Comment: What `11`? There is no `11` in the input you provided.

Comment: that is 5 numbers not 4. change it to `int a[5]`

Comment: just a bit more elaboration, `int a[4]` creates an array with 4 `int`s. These are indexed `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`, and `a[3]`. When `b == 4`, you are accessing `a[4]`, which is out of bounds of your array and invokes undefined behavior. You need to either change your array declaration to `int a[5]` or change your loop condition to `b<4`. Also of note, it's common practice to loop over arrays `< arraySize` rather than `<= arraySize-1`. Your array has 4 elements, so to touch them all, loop `b < 4`.

Comment: If it is just two conditions, why use switch instead of if

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **only** have to change the declaration of `a[4]` into `a[5]` for having a correct program. The boundaries of the iterations are correct.

What happens when you run your code is that the four first input values go into the array `a[4]` and the fifth one into the variable `b` which is allocated immediately behind the array, in your case. This is a programming error and gives unpredictible results, depending on how the compiler is allocating memory.

In your case, we can conclude that the variable `b` is stored behind the array `a[4]`, and is incremented once after you store the fifth element into what you think is the array. The place where this happens is the `b++` statement of the for loop.

I couldn't reproduce this behaviour because my compiler probably doesn't allocate `b` immediately behind `a[4]`.

Comment: Nice explanation.

Comment: Thanks  for for the details

Answer (score 0):

You are entering five numbers, not four. Change `int a[4]` to `int a[5]`. Then optionally  change all your conditions to `<5` for clarity, as this is usually what C programmers expect.

Comment: This code is working, I don't know how the array is accepting more than 4 elements but it is. Has anything changed in array implementation of C?

Comment: @Ashwani It's writing one past the bounds of the array. An array of size 4 and elements 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. The elements of an array of size `n` go from `0` to `n-1`.

Comment: Yes, I know. But this code is running. It's not throwing out of bound error which it should.

Comment: @Ashwani C doesn't have out of bounds errors, it has undefined behavior. I think you're in the wrong tag.

Comment: @Ashwani this is why you have to be more careful in C. It doesn't catch these things for you. You will start to access/modify memory that you don't intend to do or you will access memory that is outside the program's space.

Answer (score 0):

You made the array of the size 4 but you are entering 5 values in it.
So you could just increase the array size or make the loop enter 4 values by exchanging <= with < sign.
Hope it helps.